# Hide correct answer for test

Tags: php

I have a form that has a test within it that includes multiple choice checkboxes.

Each answer is pulled from Wordpress and is within a loop, each individual checkbox is output in the following way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="<?php echo $row['answer']; ?>" />
```

In Wordpress next to each answer is a checkbox, if checked then it means it's the correct answer. This is output with:

```
$row['correct'];
```

**How can I pass the data to another page to check whether the answer that the user checked was correct or not without allowing the user to view the source to see the answer?**

On the second page I'm using the following to output the answers the user checked:

```
$answer = implode(", ",$_POST["answer"]);
echo $answer;
```

Obviously these are pulled from an input within the form. How can I check if each one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are storing the answers in a JavaScript array

`<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]"...`, this could be read by PHP (on whichever page the form is posting to) by using the following:

`$answers = json_decode($_POST['answer'])`

This is assuming your form is using the `POST` method, otherwise change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

From there the `$answers[]` array can be cycled through using a `for()` loop which contains conditional expressions, i.e. `if($answers[$i] !== $correctAnswers[$i]) $wrongAnswers++ else $correctAnswers++` or similar.

This would all happen on the server side and won't be viewable by the client.

Since the user will be posted to the calculation page upon form submission, you could use `header('Location: results.php');` to direct them away from a blank page. It should be included at the end of the script after the score calculation loop.

Come to think of it, you'd probably need to store the score in a `$_SESSION[]` if you do plan on informing the user know how they did, so it can be read from the results page.

Answer (score 0):

Two acceptable ways to this as I see it:

1. Number the questions, and then have a switch statement (or map) in your PHP file to retrieve the correct answer to the question, and check it that way.
2. Set the next correct value into the session on each page and read it in the resulting PHP page.

The first option would probably be preferable.